# Fabric: Integrating service hook GitLab fails with HTTP 308

Tags: ios, gitlab, crashlytics, google-fabric

I tried integrating my GitLab Account with Fabric using the respective service hook. 
I used these parameters:

- Your GitLab URL: `https://gitlab.com/`
- Your GitLab Namespace/Project: `my projectname`
- Your GitLab Private Token:

  - New Personal Access Token created in GitLab User settings -> Access Tokens

Entering these values I get a `Could not access project "my projectname" - HTTP status code: 308` error

I also tried changing the GitLab URL to point directly at my project, then I get a 404. What am I missing here?

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. For the 308 error, you entered both the namespace and project?

Comment: @MikeBonnell if by namespace you mean my profile name then yes, I tried that. My understanding of the gitlab URL scheme is https://gitlab.com/<namespace>/<project>

Comment: Yes, you should entered namespace/project so just making sure both of those values were filled in and not just the /project value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem.
I fix it  by removing `/` at the end of the link to my gitlab server

`https://gitlab.com/`
changed to `https://gitlab.com`